# forward declaration of a derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, derived-class, forward-declaration

I want to forward declare a derived class. I have the following code:

```cpp
class B: public A;

class A { ... };
class C: public A { ... };
class B: public A { ... };
```

but this code give me some error. Whats the correct method for forward declaration of a derived class?

Comment: Where is `B` referenced that you need it forward declared?

Comment: class C used in class B but for summarization I  didn't write them.